# Popup pointing to button CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a button in my form. When I press the button i want to execute my CSS script. The CSS code shows a popup box.

**Goal**

The goal is when i click on the button it fires up my CSS popup which will be pointing to my button.

**Edit**

I managed to get the popup showing onClick but now the popup box is to far away from the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

    #myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0 ;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transperent;
    margin-top:8px;
}



    body {background:#26A9E1;padding:40px}

    #p {background:white; -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px; width:550px; height:150px}

    #pointer{border:solid 20px transparent;border-bottom-color:#fff;position:absolute;margin:-205px 00px 00px 10px;}
    
    

</style>



<body>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
    <p id="p"></p>
    <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this with just CSS unless you are after a mouse hover effect. If you want to use clicks to show/hide the popup, you'll need JS.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding JS, but i was unsuccessful in that too. @amflare

Comment: Then show that code and ask for assistance there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i was able to achieve what you want using purely css and no javascript i've made a jsfiddle:

EDIT: Here's a version using javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/7f1L9ycr/3/

Here's the version without javascript https://jsfiddle.net/7f1L9ycr/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
<button id="p" type="button">Click Me!
  <div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <div id="pointer"></div>
  </div>
</button>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body {background:#26A9E1;padding:40px; position: relative;}

p {background:white; -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 0px; width:550px; height:150px}

#pointer{border:solid 20px transparent;border-bottom-color:#fff;position:absolute;margin:-205px 00px 00px 10px;}

.container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}

#p {
  position: relative;
}

#p:focus .container {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for using both versions with/without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of CSS [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), you can't really control the logic of the interaction of a webpage too much - that's why javascript is for. I see your answer above, but I don't recommend you continue to try to go that route with things as it gets difficult to determine what's in "focus".